# how do I insert an array into a MySQL database using simple_html_dom.php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert into a MySQL database the results of these statements. The daatbase is setup correctly. When I insert into a database I get 3 dots "..." rather than what I am suppose to get. the last one for tel stores correctly, only the first two do not store into the database but only dots.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){

    foreach($html->find('span.listado_destacado',$i) as $e){
      if(!empty($e->plaintext)){
        $list[$i] = $e->plaintext;
        echo $list[$i];
      }
    }

    foreach($html->find('span.street-address',$i) as $e){
      if(!empty($e->plaintext)){
        $addr[$i] = $e->plaintext;
        echo $addr[$i];
      }
    }

    foreach($html->find('span.tel',$i) as $e){
      if(!empty($e->plaintext)){
        $tel[$i] = $e->plaintext;
        echo $tel[$i];
      }
    }

    }//for

    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
      $res=mysql_query("insert into datos (list,addr,tel) values('".$list[$i]."','".$addr[$i]."','".$tel[$i]."')");


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in for loop correct code is as follows:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){

foreach($html->find('span.listado_destacado',$i) as $e){
  if(!empty($e->plaintext)){
    $list[$i] = $e->plaintext;
    echo $list[$i];
  }
}

foreach($html->find('span.street-address',$i) as $e){
  if(!empty($e->plaintext)){
    $addr[$i] = $e->plaintext;
    echo $addr[$i];
  }
}

foreach($html->find('span.tel',$i) as $e){
  if(!empty($e->plaintext)){
    $tel[$i] = $e->plaintext;
    echo $tel[$i];
  }
}

}//for

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
  $res=mysql_query("insert into datos (list,addr,tel) values('".$list[$i]."','".$addr[$i]."','".$tel[$i]."')");


}
```

Comment: I was going to say that

Comment: sorry I had those in variables so I changed them to numbers for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [DALMP - multipleinsert](http://docs.dalmp.com/en/latest/database/multipleInsert.html) or [Dalmp - AutoExecute](http://docs.dalmp.com/en/latest/database/AutoExecute.html)

That can give you an idea of how to insert an array or multiple arrays in one shot.

Basically you prepare your array and later just insert it to the database.